# Launching Webcam in Metro style apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am building a win8 app which requires to launch the webcam for taking photos only.

I have seen the sample codes given in `MSDN` for `Camera captures` but I only want is `onclick` of `CAPTURE` Button the `webcam` should launched, take a pic and save it.

While in the sample codes they made the user to select option from the list box and on `selectionchanged`, the required function has been called. My problem is that I don't required any Listbox. Also they have used a class called `SuspensionManager` which I didn't understand. I am really confused.

Can somebody show me a way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
using Windows.Media.Capture;

var ui = new CameraCaptureUI();
ui.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3);
var file = await ui.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

if (file != null) 
{
   var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
   bitmap.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
   Photo.Source = bitmap;
}
```

Took from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimblizzard/archive/2012/04/26/simple-camera-capture-in-window-8-metro-style-application.aspx)